TagHelper order of execution in page lifecycle
Consider the below Template layout
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My Groovy Page</title>
         @await RenderSectionAsync("Styles", required: false)
        <component-styles></component-styles>
    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()
    </body>
</html>

Now consider this view.cshtml
@{
    Layout ="/path/to/layout.cshtml"
}

<component name="MyCustomTagHelper"></component>

As can be seen from the above I have created 2 custom TagHelpers, namely a component-styles tag and a component tag. The component tag goes off the the database and returns 3 important fields : Style, Script and Content.
It then :

Replaces itself with the content ( html )
Injects the script inline and wraps it in a "DOMContentLoaded" event to make sure it only fires at the correct time
Adds the Style to a Stack object stored on the Items collection of the request

It's job is then done...
Now the Component-Styles TagHelper is then responsible for interrogating the Items collection and replacing itself with all the Styles gathered by X number of components during the lifecycle of the request and outputting them. ( very much like the "styles" section would do in the traditional sense )
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    var styleContexts = ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["StyleContextItems"] as Stack<String> ?? new Stack<String>();
    output.TagName = null;
    output.Content.AppendHtml(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, styleContexts.Select(s => s).ToArray()));
}

The issue I am encountering is that the channel-styles tag helper is executing BEFORE the component tag helper and thus the Items collection is empty and therefore NO STYLES ARE OUTPUT :-(
I have fiddled with the Order variable and set the component to -100 and the styles to 100 but still no luck.
Please could someone help me out here. I need to ensure that the component-styles tag helper basically fires after all other tag helpers have been processed to achieve the correct result, but have no idea on how to achieve that.
I am also happy to change my design if there is in fact a better way that can be identified.
P.S. : the code above is wildly simplified to explain the issue. This is an entire CMS type site that is built and comipled on-the-fly and these "components" are a means of authoring reusable chunks of display functionality through a admin/management application.

To make sure your component-styles TagHelper executes after component TagHelpers, adjust their execution order by manipulating the Order property, although this alone might not solve the issue due to their targeting different elements. Consider alternatives like inline styling within components, using middleware for post-processing the response to inject styles, or employing client-side JavaScript for dynamic style application.

I have already tried manipulating the Order property but with no luck. Your middleware solution might be the trick although I would like to avoid manipulating the response if possible as I think that would have a large speed implication. ( ie reading response into streamwriter, manipulating, writing back.
Our previous iteration of our platform was based on that and the performance change since moving to compiled views has been 10 fold!

To manage style without losing performance you could consider some other options: 1)Use a dynamic section for styles in your layout, allowing components to register styles during rendering.2)use JavaScript to inject styles after component loading.3) Implement a custom event that triggers style application after component processing.4) Enhance component-styles TagHelper to render only after all components are processed.
